# Getting “Command not found” when trying to execute mounted file

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, executable

I’m not able to execute the files in a mounted directory in my Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I get the error “command not found”:

> **dseltz-VirtualBox:/local>** ls -al /nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 systemd-network uucp 49379 Oct 20  1999 /nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader
>
> **dseltz-VirtualBox:/local>** /nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader
> /nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader: Command not found.

My VM is a x64 running Ubuntu 16.04 and so is the mounted system.

I looked at the mounts and don’t see the noexec property(on either system).

Here is the mount command:

> sudo mount -o exec 10.15.1.203:/local /nfs/local

I made sure my users matched on my VM machine and the build system.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you mounted at `/nfs/local` but are trying to run a file that is in absolute path `/local`

Comment: What is the output of `file /local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader` ?

Comment: I have a logical link from /nfs/local to  /local:         sudo ln -s /nfs/local /       From either location the error is "Command not found"

Comment: dseltz-VirtualBox:/local> file /nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader
/nfs/local/gnu/i86Linux2.0/bin/makeheader: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, not stripped

Comment: Could this be a 32bit vs. 64bit issue?

Comment: Does `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` exist?

Comment: No it does not exist.  It does exist on another Ubuntu 16.04 system where the same mounted executable work.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comment from Kusalananda I found that I needed to add i386 architecture to run my 32-bit packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: your can do the install in one: `apt-get install libc6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386`